# CSS position sticky cross browser solution

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, sticky

I have a layout that is structured from 1 header and 3 vertical panels.
All vertical panels can be horizontally expanded/contracted and need to fill up together 100% width of the page. The panels also need to take 100% of the vertical space after the header (the header has an automatic height).

Each panel by itself need to be scrollable without scrolling the whole page or affecting the other panels position on the page.

[image]
[image]

The problem that I am facing is that the panels need to act both as relative positioning horizontally (so that they fill up 100% width together) but also as a fixed positioning vertically so that they stay put when scrolling.

If I use `position:sticky` it works good but is not supported by Chrome/Opera and therefore not an option.
If I use javascript, I'm having other issues when contracting/expanding since they have also animation and it just looks bad. While I can make it work, Javascript is not my desired solution at all.
I'm trying to find a pure CSS cross browser solution for it.

It is important that each panel stays scrollable without scrolling the whole page and of course have a "sticky" behavior.

I'm not a CSS expert so there probably is a simple solution that I'm missing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using `flexbox`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.flexwrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexheader {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f93;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexcontent {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.flexinner {
  flex: 1;
  background: #09f;
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.absscroll {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexwrapper">

  <div class="flexheader">
    Header
  </div>

  <div class="flexcontent">

    <div class="flexinner">
      <div class="absscroll">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexinner">
      <div class="absscroll">
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
Bla bla<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flexinner">
      <div class="absscroll">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like with this solution I'll have to change some parent elements and basic behaviour of the page. I am using Bootstrap 3, do you know if flexbox will play well with it?

Comment: @Yani Quite sure you will get this working well with bootstrap

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't as of now otherwise I would have. I'm still trying to figure out why it's not working, looks like switching to flexbox is breaking the current layout of the page.

Comment: Looks like Bootstrap is introducing flexbox in V4 - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

Comment: @Yani What actually happens then? ... screen shot?

Comment: @Yani I updated my answer with other class names so they don't collide with bootstrap ... does it work now?

Comment: Up-voted for now until I resolve it, seems like Flexbox solution is the right way to go but it still doesn't work. Will find more time to deal with this later this week.

Comment: With few changes to adapt to the current layout & Bootstrap, I was able to make it work using the Flexbox...thanks